# Trying to install libcurl on a Linux RHEL, unable to install openssl

Tags: linux, rpm, redhat-enterprise-linux, openssl

I am a programmer, and I am trying to give a clear sure fire way for the engineering team to install libcurl on a Linux RHEL machine.

The machine already has the following installed by default:

```
libcurl.so.4
libssl.so.1.0.0
libcrypto.so.1.0.0
libssh2.so.1.0.1
libcidn-2.12.so
```

And all of the above are 64 bit. What I am trying to install are 32 bit versions of the following:

```
libcurl.so.3.0.0
libssl.so.0.9.8e
libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
libcidn-2.5.so
```

I got the rpm's for most of them, but libcurl is dependent on a lot of things. And I get this error while trying to install libssl:

```
  $  rpm -ivh openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.i386.rpm
  warning: openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.i386.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 192a7d7d: NOKEY
   Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
    package openssl-1.0.0-25.el6_3.1.x86_64 (which is newer than openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.i386) is already installed
    package openssl-1.0.0-25.el6_3.1.i686 (which is newer than openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.i386) is already installed
    file /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt from install of openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.i386 conflicts with file from package ca-certificates-2010.63-3.el6_1.5.noarch
    file /etc/pki/tls/misc/CA from install of openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.i386 conflicts with file from package openssl-1.0.0-25.el6_3.1.x86_64
    file /etc/pki/tls/certs/Makefile from install of openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_5.7.i386 conflicts with file from package openssl-1.0.0-25.el6_3.1.x86_64
```

openssl does not have the compiled binaries on its page anymore. And I can only find the source rpm's online for RHEL. I tried to use a noarch one instead, but as you can see, it doesn't let me install or update.

Can you please tell me how I can force the installation in this case?

The machine OS is Linux 2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work. RHEL uses a multilib strategy in which you can install 32 and 64-bit versions of certain packages together, but *only* if they are the exact same version (architecture-independent files will be shared by both packages, so they have to be identical bit for bit). You have libcurl-4 64 bit, can only install libcurl-4 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

On this system, you have installed an RHEL 6 openssl x86-64 RPM, but you're trying to install an order RHEL 5 openssl i386 RPM. You need to install an i386 version of openssl that matches your x86-64 RPM.

The easiest way to install this would be to use `yum` rather than `rpm`.  The command to install via `yum` (with all dependencies) is:

```
yum -y install libcurl.i386
```

If you can't do that for some reason, get the openssl package you need from the RHEL updates repository, or you can use the [latest openssl RPM from CentOS 6](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/updates/x86_64/Packages/openssl-1.0.0-25.el6_3.1.i686.rpm).

Comment: So, there is no way of installing libcurl3?

Comment: Not if you have libcurl4 installed. Is there a particular reason you need libcurl3?

Comment: The engineering department bought two completely different Linux boxes. One is a RHEL5, on which the code was compiled(and hence has libcurl3), and the production box is a RHEL6(which has libcurl4), and the binary doesn't start because of the dependency.

Comment: Normally, this would be handled with a `compat` RPM. Look for a repository providing `compat-openssl` and/or `compat-libcurl3`. RH (and by extension, CentOS) doesn't provide a repository for that, so you have to evaluate third-party repositories.